# I have a bug with a true or false variable in javascript and html

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a program that is supposed to start changing its background color at the push of a button(It's not a button, it's an `<h1>`), but when I press it, the background doesn't change. It should change because of the variable change, but other than that, I think the rest works.

```
var onf = false;

setInterval(timer(), 100);

function startUp(){
document.getElementById("Temmie").textContent = "Hi";
turnOn();
}

  function turnOn(){
  document.getElementById("Tem").style.color = 'Chartreuse';
  document.getElementById("Temmie").style.fontFamily = 'Papyrus';
  document.getElementById("Temmie").style.fontSize = '24px';
  onf = true;

  }

  function timer(){
  if(onf == true){
  t = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;
  changeBackground();
  }
  }


 function changeBackground(){
 if(t == 1){
    document.body.style.background = 'ForestGreen';
 }

if(t == 2){
   document.body.style.background = 'DarkGreen';
}

if(t == 3){
   document.body.style.background = 'SteelBlue';
}
}
```

The "Tem" and "Temmie" tags are connected to a

and an , but other than that, this should be enough.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to pass the function, not the result of calling the function. The return value of `timer` is `undefined`, which is not a function or executable code.

[`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) takes a function (or a string) and calls it later after the given interval.

```
setInterval(timer, 100); // without ()
```